# Where is the MVC architecture when I use Spring Roo with GWT setup?

Tags: spring, gwt, spring-mvc, spring-roo

I'm pretty new to Spring framework but have been working with GWT for a while. Hoping to use Roo to learn Spring MVC + GWT. However, when I do gwt setup (Roo command), there's only client-side code generated with no server-side code (have persistence code though)..

Comment: IMO if you're trying to learn Spring MVC and GWT, then learn them on their own, not through something that adds an additional layer of abstraction on top of them.

Comment: If it's GWT, it generates Server side code, which would generate client side code at the runtime.

Comment: @DaveNewton: I'm hoping to learn some best practices putting the 2 together through the use of Roo. Anyway, I think I've figured out: The gwt setup in Roo integrates Spring and GWT, and not really Spring MVC. Correct me if I'm wrong, thanks.

Comment: @bhagyas: yup got that one understood, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you download the [Spring Tool Suite](http://www.springsource.com/developer/sts) (STS), which has a bunch of tutorials built into it, including Roo tutorials that walk you through all these basic steps.  The tutorials actually walk you through creating Roo projects and getting everything set up in working projects and applications.  The Suite is also full of Spring tools which make your life easier.

Comment: I'm already using it and yes, it's better to learn through STS than the stock Roo :)